# What happens to the antagonist if you sacrifice Arcadia Bay?

Tags: life-is-strange

Does anyone know or care to speculate as to what happens if Max sacrifices Arcadia Bay and choses to save Chloe??

Does the antagonist get away scott free?? Or does he go to prison?

Comment: I thought that fate of him could be he dies or gets arrested, prior to the point where you choose to sacrifice Chloe or Arcadia Bay.

Comment: I have a feeling this gets covered in the end cutscene, where he gets arrested. Obviously I can't say whether he goes to prison or not, but I believe he is escorted (from the school?) in a police car. I might be wrong, it's been a while.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [BIG timeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JhLn3.jpg) picture, the antagonist is arrested:

> After being rescued by David from the Dark Room (at this stage Chloe has been killed), Max uses the photo made outside the Vortex Club to get back in the past. Instead of going after the killer themselves, **Max informs David about the Dark Room and the killer is arrested**. Max meets Chloe at the beach and while the tornado destroys the town, she destroys the butterfly photo. After the storm Max and Chloe leave the town.

Answer (score 2):

Sacrificing Arcadia Bay is mostly an underdeveloped ending. It ends with a short cutscene of nothingness: [1](http://life-is-strange.wikia.com/wiki/Episode_5:_Polarized_-_Choices)

> Max and Chloe driving away, passing by the wreckage, with a few random people cleaning up in the distance and most (unnamed) residents are presumed dead.

Nothing more is shown and the fate of most characters is generally unknown. (So it's unknown if he gets arrested, died, etc.) The other choice *does* show what happens to him alongside an entire set of ending cutscenes.

Comment: It maybe underdeveloped but a lot of people has choosen that ending

Comment: @ng.newbie I'm not disputing that, just stating that you can't know if something happened there or not because there's no content whatsoever. As an ending it doesn't say much on any character.

Comment: IMHO it's a lot better than nullifying everything you did in these 4,5 episodes. Besides, Chloe wanted to "nuke this place and get out of here", so here you have it.

Comment: @MrScapegrace I'm not arguing which ending's better... All I said is that ending doesn't explain much, while the other does. Just stating how the endings play out, that's all.